# C# Class Field Names with dots

Tags: c#, namespaces

I am currently looking at some code with a view to making a number of changes. When looking at one of the class definitions the code has a syntax I have not seen before.

[image]

Some of the types for the fields have a prefix on them (e.g. ImplementationGuide.Package and TableModel.Row). What is this notation?

It looks like it has some relationship to the namespace where the type is defined but it is not the full namespace just the last component of it.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a partial namespace reference. This is used to distinguish between classes with the same name in different namespaces. It can be a partial because the parent namespace is either the current namespace or included in the file.

Another alternative, as @ScottChamberlain, notes is that it could be a nested class.  That is, `TableModel` is a class, not a namespace, and has an inner class named `Row`. Outside of the `TableModel` class you'd need to refer to the parent of the nested class when referencing the inner class.

Comment: Based off the names, I don't think those are namespaces, I would put money on that they are nested classes.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm just going by the OPs comment that it was related to the namespace. It could possibly be a nested class.

Comment: I take it back, the text is black not blue in the picture, if it was a nested class I think the first layer would still be blue.